# applying window level functionality on CT images in DIOCM

Tags: java, image-processing, dicom

I am trying to implement window level functionality( To apply bone, brain, lung etc on CT) for DICOM images in my application and implemented formula as per the DICOM specification.
I am changing pixel values based on below formula and creating a new image, but images are becoming blank. What am doing wrong and is this correct way to do this. Please help :(:( Thanks

```
BufferedImage image = input image;

double w = 2500; // Window width
double c = 500; // window Center
double ymin = 0;
double ymax = 255;
double x = 0;
double y = 0;
double slope = dicomObject.get(Tag.RescaleSlope).getFloat(true);
double intercept = dicomObject.get(Tag.RescaleIntercept).getFloat(true);

int width = image.getWidth();
int height = image.getHeight();

double val = c - 0.5 - (w - 1) / 2;

double val2 = c - 0.5 + (w - 1) / 2;

for (int m = 0; m < height; m++) {

    for (int n = 0; n < width; n++) {

        int rgb = image.getRGB(n, m);

        int valrgb = image.getRGB(n, m);
        int a = (0xff000000 & valrgb) >>> 24;
        int r = (0x00ff0000 & valrgb) >> 16;
        int g = (0x0000ff00 & valrgb) >> 8;
        int b = (0x000000ff & valrgb);

        x = a + r + g + b;

        if (x <= val)
            y = ymin;

        else if (x > val2)
            y = ymax;

        else {
            y = ((x - (c - 0.5)) / (w - 1) + 0.5) * (ymax - ymin)+ ymin;
        }
        y = y * slope + intercept;
        rgb = (int) y;
        image.setRGB(n, m, rgb);

    }
}
String filePath = "out put fileName";
ImageIO.write(image, "jpeg", new File(filePath));
```

Comment: You are assuming that the input image has 8 bit per color component, and the same for the output, but the window width and center you specified in the code are for higher bit depths (16 for instance)

Comment: CT images are typically 16-bit greyscale, you will also need to account for Rescale slope/intercept when considering the window/level, all of this will lead to an output of 8-bits for display.  For more info see [DICOM Part 3.3](http://medical.nema.org/medical/dicom/2014a/output/pdf/part03.pdf), section "C.8.2.1 CT Image Module".

Comment: Thanks for reply Chris, When i am using 16-bit greyscale as int valrgb = image.getRGB(n, m);int a = (0xff000000 & valrgb) >>> 48;int r = (0x00ff0000 & valrgb) >> 32;int g = (0x0000ff00 & valrgb) >> 16;int b = (0x000000ff & valrgb); image goes completely grey. what i am doing wrong ? is require any change while setting new pixel value?? Please

Answer (score 2):

First of all whats in your BufferedImage image ?
There are three steps you want to take from raw (decopressed) pixel data:

1. Get stored values - apply BitsAllocated, BitsStored, HighBit transformation. (I guess you image already passed that level)
2. Get modality values - thats your Slope, Intercept transformation. Ofter this transformation, your data will be in Hounsfield Units for CT.
3. Then you apply WW/WL (Value Of Interest) transformation, which will transform this window of walues into grayscale color space.

**EDIT:**

You've got to tell me where did you get "input image" from? After decompression pixel data should be in a byte array of size byte[width*height*2] (for CT Image BitsAllocated is always 16, thus *2). You can get stored values like this:

```
ushort code = (ushort)((pixel[0] + (pixel[1] << 8)) & (ushort)((1<<bitsStored) - 1));
int value = TwosComplementDecode(code);
```

Comment: Hi Witek Thanks, I am new in DICOM, i don't have any document that describe step by step solution to apply window level functionality. The 1st step(Get stored values) you mentioned, i have not go through with that, How can i apply bit allocated, bit stored and high bit transformation? Please

Comment: Updated answer. As I said - I don't know whats in your BufferedImage image.

Comment: Thanks Witek, buffered image i am taking as : BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\images\\101.jpg")); and process buffered image. Is this right??

Comment: The file 101.jpg is converted from DICOM of Type CT.

Comment: First of all you should extract pixel data from a .dcm file (using some library). Image in DICOM contains values of some kind (i.e. Hounsfield Units), not colors like in your .jpeg (unles your .jpeg file is extracted from DICOM).

Comment: How did you convert it? Most likely all the transformations have been applied (including default WW/WL). in this case you can reverse the default transformation(getting modality values HU), and then apply your custom WW/WL.

Comment: (that way you won't know what happened to the values outside of the default window, so the custom window cant be wider then the default)

Comment: HI Witek, I am converting DICOM to jpeg as : 1st convert DICOM to byte array and after that get pixel as buffered image as ImageIO.getImageReadersByFormatName("DICOM") and using DicomImageReadParam read pixel data as bufferd image. now buffered image write as ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "jpeg", file);

Comment: I am working on to extract Pixel data from .dcm as you suggested, after get success let you know. and proceed to next step.

Comment: Hi Witek, When i am trying to get pixel data using , short[] pixelData = dicomObject.getShorts(Tag.PixelData); or int pixelData[] = dicomObject.get(Tag.PixelData).getInts(false); its showing java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException . So how can i get pixel data from DICOM??

Comment: Hi Witek, Now i am getting pixel data as byte array As: byte[] pixelData = decodeMessage(getPixelData().get(0)); And readPixelData() read pixel using DicomElement dicomElement = dcmObj.get(Tag.PixelData); I am getting pixel data in this way , is this right? And using this a am calculating stored value as you specified above and apply DICOM Specification formula on that value. and after applying transform set to pixel array but image goes to blank.